# Using setInterval() to make data reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a video component passing data from an async GET request to a child component:

```
// Inside a v-for loop
<video
    :title="video.title"
    :id="video._uid"
>
// ...
<Controls :videoData="video" />
```

When receiving the prop in `Controls` I then use that data to select the video by it's `id` in the DOM and set data properties according to that element:

```
created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.video = document.getElementById(this.videoData._uid);
        this.videoDuration = this.video.duration;

        setInterval(() => {
            this.videoCurrentTime = this.video.currentTime;
            this.videoPlaying = !this.video.paused;
            this.videoVolume = this.video.volume;
        }, 1);
    }, 1000);
}
```

The `setTimeout` is to get around the data being asynchronous and the `setInterval` is to continuously update the data, such as the current time of the video, whether it's paused or not, etc.

It works exactly as it should, but it seems really inefficient. What if someone has slow internet and it takes longer than 1000ms to fetch the data, for example.

I would think the fact it's in a `v-for` loop would prevent the need for `setTimeout` as the component wouldn't exist before the video has been fetched. I must be missing something.

Request:

```
created() {
    this.fetchVersion().then(async () => {
        await Axios.get(
            `https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/videos?version=published&token=<STORYBLOK_TOKEN>&cv=${this.getVersion}`
        ).then(res => {
            res.data.story.content.body.forEach(i => {
                this.storyblokVideos.push(i);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Does anyone have a better way of making the data reactive?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @potato's answer:

I set a data property called `isLoading: true` then used the video's event `oncanplay` to conditionally load the controls: `@canplay="isLoading = false"`. No more async errors. Then I used the different events to pass data:

```
@play="playing = true"
@pause="playing = false"
@timeupdate="updateCurrentTime()"
@volumechange="updateVolume()"
```

Much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use events and callbacks to react to things as they happen instead of repeatedly checking for changes.

You can use the `.then` function to do whatever needs to be done once the data is received.

You can learn about the `<video>` element events here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: Good spot! Can always rely on a potato. I'll update my question to reference your answer